# Is it ok to commit to git while my Unity project is still open?

Tags: unity, git

I tend to have big commits and it is related to me being tool lazy to close Rider and Unity, commit changes and then start both programms back up to make changes and repeat. I just assumed that this is the correct way of doing it, but is this even the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git does not work with your memory ram. git works with what is in hard-disk. it means git commits everything you saved. so it means you can commit when unity is open. just save every thing before you commit and push.

Comment: I was afraid of unity maybe saving some things (like .meta files - idk) to disk only when it is closed. Thank you!

Comment: no. unity automatically always update them for you. just dont forget to set gitignore file before first commit @bartimaeus

Comment: Remember to hit File -> Save Project, which ensures things like those meta files get committed to disc.